# Como insertar una imagen en bytes a la base de datos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, imagen

Tengo un sistema web con una tabla de BD que tiene una variable en varbinary llamada ImagPromo. Esta es la función con la que añado un nuevo valor a la tabla.

```
SqlConnection cn = Conexion.Instancia.Conectar();
cmd = new SqlCommand("spNuevoPromocion", cn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmstrNomPromo", p.NombrePromocion);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmstrDesPromo", p.Descripcion);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmdecDscPromo", p.Descuento);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmdatFInicio", p.FechaInicial);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmdatFFinal", p.FechaFinal);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmstrImgPromo", p.ImgPromo);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmstrDocPDF", p.DocPDF);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prmstrImagPromo", p.ImagPromo);
cn.Open();
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando quiero añadir un dato con una imagen nueva a la tabla desde el sistema web, me sale este error: "La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 válida porque contiene un carácter que no es Base 64, más de dos caracteres de relleno o un carácter no válido entre los caracteres de relleno." He escrito unas líneas para convertir la imagen en bytes, pero no se ejecutan. ¿En dónde tengo que colocarlas para que funcionen?

```
public ActionResult NuevoPromocion(entPromocion p)
    {
        bandera = false;
        try
        {
            bandera = logPromocion.Instancia.InsertaPromocion(p);
            HttpPostedFileBase FileBase = Request.Files[0];
            WebImage image = new WebImage(FileBase.InputStream);
            p.ImagPromo = image.GetBytes();
            if (bandera)
            {
                TempData.Add("Mensaje", "Los datos se registraron correctamente");
                return RedirectToAction("ListaPromocion");
            }
            else
            { return View(p); }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ListaPromocion", "Error", new { mensajerror = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pues, antes de insertarpromoción, no?

Comment: Hola, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util

Answer (score 1):

```
static class UtilImagen
{
    public static byte[] ImagenToByteArray(string rutaImagen)
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(rutaImagen);
    }

    public static Image ByteArrayToImagen(byte[] byteImage)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteImage))
        {
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta clase tiene dos métodos:

**Método 1:**

```
public static byte[] ImagenToByteArray(string rutaImagen)
```

Recibe como parámetro un **string** que representa la ruta de la imagen, esta ruta será utilizada por el **método ReadAllBytes** de la **clase File** para convertir la imagen a un **arreglo de bytes**. La función devuelve un **arreglo de bytes** que es el tipo de datos que acepta la base de datos para guardar imágenes.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rutaImagen))
{
   contacto.ImagenPerfil = UtilImagen.ImagenToByteArray(rutaImagen);
}
```

**Método 2:**

```
public static Image ByteArrayToImagen(byte[] byteImage)
```

Hace lo inverso al método anterior, si el otro método convierte a **arreglo de bytes**, pues este convierte de **arreglo de bytes** a **Image** (tipo de dato usado en **C#** para visualizar imágenes). Recibe como parámetro el **arreglo de bytes** (formato en que la imagen está guardada en la base de datos) y lo convierte al tipo de dato **Image**.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
imagenPerfilPictureBox.Image = UtilImagen.ByteArrayToImagen(contacto.ImagenPerfil);
```

Analiza este código y adáptalo al tuyo.