# Subir un picturebox a sql server

Tags: c#, sql, bitmap, picturebox

Buenos dias para preguntarles si pueden ayudarme a encontrar una solucion el caso es el siguiente cree con dos picturebox uno habra la camara del dispositivo y cuando se presiona un boton toma una foto y lo almacena en un picturebox entonces cuando  quiero subir esa imagen a la base de datos me marca el siguiente error:

> no mapping exists from object type System.Drawing.BItmap to known managed provider native type

este es  el codigo que estoy usando
Aqui lo convierto a bytes

```
      public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imagen)
           {
              MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
              imagen.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
              return ms.ToArray();
            }
```

y aqui lo guardo

```
 private void metroButton2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                        
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBox2.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            



            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:prueba-prueba.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Gestion;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
            
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
            conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                
                comando.Connection = conexion;
                byte[] byteArrayImagen = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox2.Image);
                comando.CommandText = "insert into Prueba(@Imagen) values(@Imagen)";
                comando.Parameters.Clear();
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen",pictureBox2.Image);
                int NFilas = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (NFilas > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro Guardado correctamente");
                }

            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Boleta duplicada" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Que tipo de aplicacion estas elaborando windows forms, webform,...? y agrega la version del framework

Comment: es windows form y el framwork es 5

Comment: nunca usas byteArrayImagen supongo que ese es el valor a guardar. byte[] byteArrayImagen = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox2.Image);
            comando.CommandText = "insert into Prueba(@Imagen) values(@Imagen)";
            comando.Parameters.Clear();
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen",pictureBox2.Image);

Comment: funciono ya lo registra pero al consultar la base de datos no muestra la foto que se guarda sino muchos caracteres

Comment: @AnthonyDioneyValdez eso es un problema diferente porque no sabemos cómo lo estás consultando ni viendo. Posiblemente estás viendo el bitmap como si fuese un varchar y pues... por ahí no es :)

Comment: @MiguelZarate ponlo como respuesta y, si se termina de resolver lo que indica el OP, puede ser la respuesta aceptada :)

Comment: Revisa este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426998/como-insertar-una-imagen-en-bytes-a-la-base-de-datos/427043#427043